# Simple jQuery Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I have a page with about 50 divs on it. I would like to organise these divs into groups of six, so that the client doesn't get 'information overload'. I have created a simple [example/reduced test case](http://jsfiddle.net/hyvZN/) of my problem. As you can see, there a lots of divs, and I want it so that when the page loads, only the first six are visible, but when you click on page 2 or next, the next six are revealed et cetera. The class of the page number you are on should also be set to have `class="current"`.

So far I have tried using jQuery, but I have been getting quite stuck! Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you thought about a tabbed view instead of a pagination. I just think that a pagination makes more sense in cases like a grid, but for dividing complete content I guess a tabview is better

Comment: Yes you are right, in your case a pagination makes kind of more sense.

Comment: There are tons of jQuery plugins for this. For example: http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When a page is requested, hide all content divs, then iterate through them and show those that should appear on the "page":

```
showPage = function(page) {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".content").each(function(n) {
        if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
            $(this).show();
    });        
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jfm9y/184/

Comment: Have a doubt why do u want use parseInt though u can show the text by using this.text()

Answer (score 5):

Parts of this code is not pretty but I think it does the job

```
var currentpage = 1;
var pagecount = 0;

function showpage(page) {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.content').eq((page-1)*6).show().next().show().next().show().next().show().next().show().next().show();
    $('#pagin').find('a').removeClass('current').eq(page).addClass('current');

}

$("#pagin").on("click", "a", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($(this).html() == "next") {
        currentpage++;
    }
    else if($(this).html() == "prev") {
        currentpage--;
    } else {
            currentpage = $(this).html();
    }
    if(currentpage < 1) {currentpage = 1;}
    if(currentpage > pagecount) {currentpage = pagecount;}
    showpage(currentpage);
});                                                                  

$(document).ready(function() {
    pagecount = Math.floor(($('.content').size()) / 6);
    if (($('.content').size()) % 6 > 0) {
        pagecount++;
    }

    $('#pagin').html('<li><a>prev</a></li>');
    for (var i = 1; i <= pagecount; i++) {
        $('#pagin').append('<li><a class="current">' + i + '</a></li>');
    }
    $('#pagin').append('<li><a>next</a></li>');
    showpage(1);

});​
```

Comment: Any time you see code like `$('.content').eq((page-1)*6).show().next().show().next().show().next().show().next().show().next().show();` it's a candidate for using a loop.  Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

The following code is taken from https://deltafrog.com/pagination-jquery-without-plugin/

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
var item_per_page=5;
var $block=jQuery('.block');
var block_count=$block.length;
var number_of_pages=Math.ceil(block_count/item_per_page);

//append pagination in body
jQuery('body').append("<div class='pagination'></div>");
for(var i=1; i<=number_of_pages; i++){
    jQuery('.pagination').append("<div class='page'>"+i+"</div>");  
}

//activate first page
jQuery(".page:first-child").addClass('active');
jQuery('.block').filter(function( index ) { return index < item_per_page;}).addClass('active');

//activate pagination on click
jQuery('body').delegate('.page','click',function(){
    var page_index=jQuery(this).index();
    var start=page_index*item_per_page;
    $block.removeClass('active');
    jQuery(".page").removeClass('active');
    jQuery(".page").eq(page_index).addClass('active');
    for(var j=0;j<item_per_page;j++){
        $block.eq(start+j).addClass('active');
    }

});

});
```