# how to use jquery to get the pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination

```
<  1 2 3 4 5 ...26 >
<... 4 5 6 7 8 ...26 >
    how to  use  j-query  to use this type of pagination.
 i do not want to use the  existing plugins.

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    var j=0;
    var s=0;
    var k;
    var t;
    $("li").hide();
     for (k=0;k<6;k++){
         $("#l"+k).show();
         }
     s=1;
    $("#next").click(function(){
        s=s+1;

        // alert("s =" + s);
         t=(s*5);
         //alert("t ="+t); 
         if(s>0){
             i=(s-1)*5;
            // alert( "i value"+i);
             }   
         $("li").hide();   

        while(i<t){                      
        $("#l"+(i+1)).show();
        i++;
        }       
        if(t>$("list1 li").length)
            then (s=0);        
    });
    $("#back").click(function(){
        if(j<6){
        $("#l"+j).hide();
        j++;
        }
        else{j=0;}

    });
});
</script>
```

the code is working fine with  forward/next">"  but i am unable to get  any reference for the  previous "<" at any instant

suggest if there is any other way to use it 
 how to  use  j-query  to use this type of pagination.
     i do not want to use the  existing plugins.

Comment: There are several plugins available built on jquery to facilitate pagination. You can Google them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple jQuery Pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034724/simple-jquery-pagination)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of pagination examples available [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/)