# Swap the position of list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the position of the list item. I have 5 list item 1st and 5th item is prev and next button. I want to swap the position of the list item.

I want to keep the position of the 1st and 5th item as it is and need to swap 2nd,3rd and 4th list item. By default on load I want to make the 3rd item as center (28) and next button click want to make '27' as center and on next click want to make '26' as center and again '28'.

Now position not working properly.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       var node_id = 28;
       $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item) {
            $(item).find('.' + node_id).insertAfter($(item).find('li:eq(1)'));
        });
 $('.flex-next').click(function() {
   $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item) {
   var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
   var thirdLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(3)").addClass("animated slideInLeft",1000);
   var firstLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)").addClass("animated fadeInRight",1000);
   var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)").addClass("animated slideInRight",1000);
   $(secondLi).before(fourthLi);
        });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content__teaser col-md-12">
    <ul class="thumbnailIcon flex-direction-nav">
       <li class="flex-nav-prev"><a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a></li>
       <li class="26 animated fadeInRight">26</li>
       <li class="28 animated slideInRight">28</li>
       <li class="27 animated slideInLeft">27</li>
       <li class="flex-nav-next"><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li></ul>    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple jQuery Pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034724/simple-jquery-pagination)

Comment: @mxr7350 - No. It's not a duplicate.

Comment: @Pugazh he is trying to make pagination, right?

Comment: no I'm not trying to make paginaton.this concept is entirly different

Comment: Yes, but within pagination OP wants to position the current page as the center element.(In the example you can see 28 before 27)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you want.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var list = $('.thumbnailIcon');
  var firstItem, secondItem, thirdItem;
  updateItemVariables();
  
  $('.flex-next').click(function() {
    thirdItem.after(firstItem);
    
    updateItemVariables();
  });
  
  function updateItemVariables() {
    firstItem = list.find("li:nth-child(2)");
    secondItem = list.find("li:nth-child(3)");
    thirdItem = list.find("li:nth-child(4)");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content__teaser col-md-12">
  <ul class="thumbnailIcon flex-direction-nav">
    <li class="flex-nav-prev"><a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="26 animated fadeInRight">26</li>
    <li class="28 animated slideInRight">28</li>
    <li class="27 animated slideInLeft">27</li>
    <li class="flex-nav-next"><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```